# Is $x^2+x+1$ reducible in $K=\frac{\mathbb{F_5}[x]}{x^2+2x+3}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $$K=\frac{\mathbb{F_5}[x]}{x^2+2x+3}$$ I have proven that K is a field. Now, how can I see that $x^2+x+1$ is reducible in $K$? Furthermore, how do I calculate the roots of $x^2+x+1$ in $K$? I am not sure if I can use the quadratic formula $\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$ here, since I don't know if $1/2$ is in $K$.

Comment: Do you mean $X^2+X+1\in K[X]$ is irreducible? Note that $x$ (or, more precisely, its equivalence class) is already an element of $K$.

Comment: $1/2$ is absolutely in $K$. It's in $\mathbb{F}_5$, and $\mathbb{F}_5$ is contained in $K$.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach: $\mathbb{F}_5$ has a unique extension of degree $2$ so any quadratic must have a root there. So if you proved that $K$ is a field, it must be that degree $2$ extension.

Comment: Why does it have a unique extension of degree $2$?

Comment: This is one of the most basic facts on finite fields that they have a unique extension of each degree. Specifically, the reason we have a unique quadratic extension of F_5 is that all the elements of a quadratic extension must satisfy $x^{25}-x=0$. This is not a full proof but rather the key idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $(x+3)^2+(x+3)+1=x^2+2x+3$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$.